# Want to make a tsne plot show subset

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am new to `R`. I make a tsne plot for my data "yfp". And there are two subsets in my data (yfppt and yfpng). I want to show their distribution or location in yfp tsne plot but failed. And I even did not set legend but problem indicates error in legend.

I use RStudio to run the [RaceID package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RaceID/vignettes/RaceID.html).

This is the coding I made for subset:

```
yfpng<-data2[, 1:55]
yfppt<-data2[, 56:124]
```

This is the coding I tried to make distribution of subsets in tsne plot:

```
types <- sub("(\\_\\d+)$","", colnames(yfp@ndata))
subset <- types[grep("yfppt|yfpng",types)]
plotsymbolsmap(yfp,types,subset=subset,fr=TRUE)
```

> Error in legend("topleft", legend = sort(unique(types[fp])), col =
>   samples_col,  : 'legend' is of length 0

I expect to output the distribution of two subset(yfppt and yfpng) in yfp tsne plot and there is a legend showing which dots are yfppt and yfpng respectively.